# What is the correct way to optimise scrolling performance of NSImageView and NSView

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview

I need to improve the scrolling performance of a view for annotating on top of an image.

Currently I have the following:

```
- annotationView (custom NSView)
- imageView (NSImageView)
- contentView (custom NSView)
- clipView (NSClipView)
- scrollView (NScrollView)
```

The images are quite large PDFs and PNGs and scrolling is poor unless I make the imageView layer backed, which I am just doing in Interface Builder.  Scrolling is then pretty smooth.

However the PNG images override everything on top of the imageView, whereas the PDF images remain correctly in the background.

Why is this and how can I fix that?

To get even better performance I would also like to make the annotationView layer backed as well but if I do that the entire view becomes black - with the exception of the annotations being draw on the annotationView.  How can I make this layer backed view transparent but still allow for the shapes to be draw on it.  It seems I can make it transparent but then everything becomes transparent, including the drawn shapes.

Is there a better way to achieve this?  The annotations are simply shapes and text that need to be placed at specific positions over the image which I am currently just drawing in response to mouse positions.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use layer backed views and use `CGContext` for drawing and not the simpler `NSView` drawing APIs.

By default macOS does not use GPU based graphics, unlike iOS.

macOS provides a high level API that uses the CPU rather than the GPU for graphics operations.

So in my case I switched everything to `layer backed NSViews` - you can set this in Interface Builder or simply add '`wantsLayer = true`' in the `NSView` initialisation code (`init()`).

Avoid using `NSImageView`, instead use a layer backed view and set the `layer.content = NSIMage`, you may have to also set the layers background colour or you might get some areas of the background not being cleared when scrolling.

This works for me - I have big PDF images in the background - building layouts and a layer backed view on top of that for placing annotations.

Scrolling around is now buttery smooth.  Images seem to load instantly.

For the most part its pretty easy - just set up right from the start and save yourself a lot of headaches.